# Hadoop on Hybrid Cloud

Tags: hadoop, cloud, hybrid-cloud, bigdata

What does it mean by running Hadoop on both on-premise and cloud? Does this mean the nodes in same hadoop cluster is provisioned on both on-premise and public cloud?

What are my options if i have keep the data on-premise but compute is on the public cloud? It may be against the fundamental principal of hadoop where data locality is important.

What are the hybrid cloud providers that offers big data platforms?

Comment: Yes hybrid cloud basically means you can have nodes both on premise and off premise. Think if you want to expand your on premise cluster even temporarily or just add some nodes. You could add them from your cloud environment. Usually Hadoop services like mapreduce compute on the same node where the data lives. It is also replicated to usually 2 other nodes it could use. I am not sure what your compute env is to say for sure. For core Hadoop I don't think it would really make a difference if implemented properly.

Comment: @Blake any pointers to set up hadoop on hybrid cloud? On data locality, what i meant was that if i have an option to keep my data on-premise and use the public cloud for compute then compute cannot happen on the same node where data resides.

Comment: That is kind of vague, it can really depend. In my experience sticking with proven software vendors. Most of the cloud providers such as AWS, Microsft Azure, and Google Cloud have various options you can use to build this out. Some of these vendors have packaged Hadoop to put in their cloud, I find this often makes client software have compatibility issues. Hadoop vendors such as Cloudera or Hortonworks can provide support if you need, they also support hybrid cloud on their platform. They also easily integrate with client software and often supported by third party software.

Comment: I would decide on a operating system, Linux of course, that I can use both on prem and off premise then build out my hybrid cloud from scratch. During your setup you can pick the Hadoop cluster architecture/topology to pick which nodes have which services. You can have more than 1 instance of a service. So if you want something like HiveServer2 which is common you can run that on one of the nodes on prem and off.

Comment: Let me put it this way. What are the options to set up hybrid hadoop cluster? If i run a job on an hybrid cluster, i understand as per response "Yes hybrid cloud basically means you can have nodes both on premise and off premise." that the job runs on the nodes both on premise and hybrid.